# Return positive numbers of a list in python

Tags: python, list, printing, return

I'm new to python. I was wondering how i could return and convert the list below into positive numbers. that would

Print:

> [1, 5, 2, 10]

```
def func(a):
    return abs(a)

print func(a=[1,-5,2,-10])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call the `abs` function once per element and get the list resulting from doing that. That's exactly what `map` is for:

```
return map(abs, a)
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
return [abs(n) for n in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1, -5, 2, -10]
>>> b = [abs(x) for x in a]
>>> print b
[1, 5, 2, 10]
>>>
```

As Claudiu points out, the [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) function in the standard library would work as well. The Python community tends to prefer using list comprehensions where possible, though, since it usually makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more detailed answer:

```
def func(a):
  for item in a:
    yield abs(a)

print list(func(a=[1,-5,2,-10]))
```